# Redirect to diferent paths depending from where do you acces a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the same form in two different sites of the application and depending from where I access to the form I want to be redirected to different paths after submitting it.

This is what I have in my controller:

```
def create
 @item = Offer.new(offer_params)

 authorize @item

 if @item.save
  condition_I_don't_know_how_to_write ? redirect_to(x_path) : redirect_to(y_path) 
 else
  render :new
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out the URL where the request originated with `request.referrer`. It will give you the whole URL in the format `https://example.com/products/1`. You can then quite easily extract the information you need from that URL, for example the path with `URI(request.referrer).path`, which would in this example return `/products/1`.

Another option would be to use [nested routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). This way you could have your `request.path` be something like `/products/1/offers/new`, which is less ambiguous and avoids the hassle of getting the `request.referrer` and then extracting the path from that.